# How to avoid that an specific character typed in the textbox shows up using JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox

```
<input type="text" name="indice" class="number">
<br>
```

I want to make sure that when someone types a comma ',' in this textbox it's automatically blocked and don't even shows up in the textbox.

What's the better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Attach **[`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)** event handler and prevent the event when pressed key is comma(`,`). You can get the pressed key code by **[`event.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)** property.

```js
// bind the keydown event handler
$('.number').keydown(function(e) {
  // check which key pressed `188` represents comma
  if (e.which == 188)
  // if comma is pressed prevent the default event action
    e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="indice" class="number">
<br>
```

---

The same with pure JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector('.number').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 188)
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="indice" class="number">
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#textboxid").keydown(function(){
       if($("#textboxid").val().index of(",")!=-1)
                $("#textboxid").prop("readonly",true)
})
```